# Copy SSRS report content to clipboard

Tags: asp.net, gridview, reporting-services

I have a button("Copy to Clip") in each row of a Gridview. On this buttton click I want to copy a SSRS report which is stored in database in binary format to Clipboard. Can somebody help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax call to your report server using url parameters to get the report in the format you want.

CSV would be a good format to paste into your clipboard.

```
http://localhost/reportserver?/Folder/report&param=val&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=CSV
```

Then use a library like [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) to paste the contents to clipboard. Its cross browser compatible as it uses flash.